How to variable-ize a cell reference in google sheets
I'm doing a very simple formula... just an =another cell in another sheet in the same workbook.
='Form Responses'!C4
Is there a way to set the 4 in C4 above, to point to another cell (let's say A1), that contains the character 4? What's the right syntax?
Tried lots of different concatenation techniques (&", +, and others)
Thanks in advance!


You may try:
=indirect("Form Responses!C"&A1)

